# How to add metadata to images using Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

Using Ubuntu 13.04.

I have a very basic question about Shotwell.

I would like to add a desciption to my photos.

I right-click on an image in Nautilus. 
Choose Open with > Shotwell photo viewer.

I can't find a way to edit any metadata for the photo.

As an example, Shotwell help:

http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/view-view.html

... says that I should be able to select Photos > Edit title, but I don't have this option in my menu. (I have 'Photo' but not 'Photos'). F2 does nothing for me.

My menu options are: File, Edit, View, Photo, Help.

I'm missing something very basic here. Grateful for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Such a feature is only available in Shotwell itself. 'Shotwell photo viewer' lacks all advanced features and is, as its name suggests, only ment for viewing images.

**How To:** Open Shotwell, and if you haven't done this yet, import your photo collection by setting its location in the preferences window.

Now you can edit the title, comments and tags of any photo. (by right clicking it, or using the options under 'Photo' in the menubar)

Shotwell can save this meta-data in the image files them-self, or in a separate database. This can be set in the preferences window.

Comment: You can view extended information, but not edit it. and only a minimal amount of metadata is available

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!  But this functionality should be provided in the viewer also. As described by the Library of Congress at  http://blogs.loc.gov/digitalpreservation/2011/10/mission-possible-an-easy-way-to-add-descriptions-to-digital-photos/ it is an important, basic feature to see and add a description to a photo. At the least, the menu item should be grayed out, and this should be explained in the documentation.  It is very confusing to have the documentation list an option which isn't there. See more at my bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell/+bug/1393463

Answer (score 3):

If you open Shotwell, double click on the image to preview it, then click on Photo item on the main menu you get the options to Set rating, Edit Title, Edit Comment and Adjust Date and Time

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  But as the OP found, this Edit Title menu item is not visible when shotwell is run from the file manager or the command line (i.e. in some sort of "viewer" mode).  Sad.  See my bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shotwell/+bug/1393463

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative is to use the [gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gthumb) viewer instead.

It allows editing Comment/description fields from the right-click menu or with the `C` keyboard shortcut.

```
sudo apt install gthumb
```